# Apex Class - formal parameters must follow specific conventions

Tags: apex, pmd

I have this small class which has a red line under the method name like in the snip. I believe it has something to do with the parameter naming convention, not sure what I am doing wrong here. This is message I see when I hover over it **formal parameters must follow specific conventions**.
[image]
Could somebody advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't an error, just a warning. It's not a standard thing, but provided by the static code analysis tool, Apex PMD.

A quick search for the issue raised yields this page/anchor: https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_codestyle.html#formalparameternamingconventions

> Configurable naming conventions for formal parameters of methods. This rule reports formal parameters which do not match the regex that applies to their specific kind (e.g. method parameter, or final method parameter). Each regex can be configured through properties.
>
> By default this rule uses the standard Apex naming convention (Camel case).

Apex PMD seems to say that the first letter is lower-case for camelCase, which your parameter name violates (camelCase can technically start with either a lower or upper case letter, but starting with an uppercase letter is the convention for apex Objects/Classes, and would be what I'd call TitleCase)

Beyond that though, `Id` is a poor choice of variable name. If it's an `Id`, you ought to be using the `Id` type, and in any case, the variable name should be more specific (e.g. `accountId`, `caseId`, `myCustomObjectId`).

Using identifiers that match existing types/classes can cause issues (though generally only when you shadow a built-in class name or keyword like `Account` or `Test`).

Comment: Thanks Derek, changing the Id to documentId fixed it.